# English to Russian Computer-science / Programming dictionary

Tags: перевод, resources, информатика, словарь

Is there an authoritative English-Russian dictionary/reference for computer-science and programming terms?

In most cases I just use transliterations of English terms while speaking. Is there a good reference for established Russian terminology in CS and programming?

Comment: Transliteration is something you can only do in writing. Anyway, I'd suggest just sticking with the English terms, due to the nature of the business professionals are more likely to understand you that way. We still haven't adopted a canonical translation for "options", and more complex terms are much harder to translate.

Answer (score 3):

The [Англо-русский словарь по компьютерной безопасности](http://computer_security_en_ru.academic.ru/) might fit your bill.